# React Array State Update Not Consistant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Having a weird problem, hoping someone can assist. I'm trying to "iterate" through an array of words and punctuation in order to make the appearance of scrolling dialogue. I have this working except for when I try to push it to React, it just goes...haywire. Here's what I have:

```
export default function DialogueBox(params){

    const params="The story, characters, and events, in this game are entirely fictional. Any similarities to actual people, places and events are entirely coicidental.";

    let dialogueValue = [];

    let [dialogue, setDialogue] = useState([]);
  
    let letterArray = params.text.split(/\b/);

    const handleChangeValue = text => {
       
                const updatedLettersArray = [...dialogueValue, text];
                console.log('updated: ' + updatedLettersArray);
                // setDialogue(oldArray=>[...oldArray,updatedLettersArray]);
                
    }

    return (
        <div className="dialogueBox">
            {letterArray.forEach(function(element,index){
                setTimeout(
                    function(){
                        handleChangeValue(element);
                        dialogueValue.push(element);
                    }, index * 500
                );
            })}
            <p>{dialogue}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here's the console log, which is correct:

```
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, ,to DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, ,to, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, ,to, ,actual DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, ,to, ,actual, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, ,to, ,actual, ,people DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, ,to, ,actual, ,people,, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, ,to, ,actual, ,people,, ,places DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, ,to, ,actual, ,people,, ,places, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, ,to, ,actual, ,people,, ,places, ,and DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, ,to, ,actual, ,people,, ,places, ,and, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, ,to, ,actual, ,people,, ,places, ,and, ,events DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, ,to, ,actual, ,people,, ,places, ,and, ,events, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, ,to, ,actual, ,people,, ,places, ,and, ,events, ,are DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, ,to, ,actual, ,people,, ,places, ,and, ,events, ,are, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, ,to, ,actual, ,people,, ,places, ,and, ,events, ,are, ,entirely DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, ,to, ,actual, ,people,, ,places, ,and, ,events, ,are, ,entirely, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, ,to, ,actual, ,people,, ,places, ,and, ,events, ,are, ,entirely, ,coicidental DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story,, ,characters,, ,and, ,events,, ,in, ,this, ,game, ,are, ,entirely, ,fictional,. ,Any, ,similarities, ,to, ,actual, ,people,, ,places, ,and, ,events, ,are, ,entirely, ,coicidental,.
```

but, if I uncomment that line

```
// setDialogue(oldArray=>[...oldArray,updatedLettersArray]);
```

the following happens:

```
updated: The 94 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The 3 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 3 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 3 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 3 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 3 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story 3 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story 3 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story 2 DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, DialogueBox.js:15
updated: The, ,story
```

Basically just repeating itself non stop. I'm positive i'm missing something obvious here but i'm at a loss! Thank you all for any help

Comment: Is there a reason you're naming your parameter `params` and then also declaring a variable named `params`?

Comment: Yeah, this is a component and I wanted some test data in there for folks to see. That line isn't in the actual program itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `setInterval` and an `index` to keep track of position. Check out example here https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-wind-sq8lb?file=/src/App.js:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const sentence =
    "The story, characters, and events, in this game are entirely fictional. Any similarities to actual people, places and events are entirely coicidental.";

  const [dialogue, setDialogue] = useState("");
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const letterArray = sentence.split(/\b/);

  const handleChangeValue = () => {
    if (letterArray[index] !== undefined) {
      setDialogue((dialogue) => dialogue + letterArray[index]);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // update the dialogue here
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (index < letterArray.length) {
        setIndex((index) => index + 1);
      }
    }, 100);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // update the dialogue here
    handleChangeValue();
    console.log(`New dialogue: ${dialogue}`);
  }, [index]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{dialogue}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ninjadave. This is perfect and exactly what I needed.

Comment: @sylargaf You're welcome

Answer (score 1):

Don't use setTimeout directly within the React component return, it will setup massive of timers into Javascript runtime and never be recycled.

If the setTimeout or even setInterval is what you needed, wrap them with useEffect would be the idea

By guessing what you're trying to do, this is an example code. It will display a word every 0.5s to the screen till the end of params

```
export default function DialogueBox(params){

  const params = "The story, characters, and events, in this game are entirely fictional. Any similarities to actual people, places and events are entirely coicidental.";
  const letters = params.split(/\b/)

  const [dialogue, setDialogue] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timers = []

    letters.forEach((letter, index) => {
      timers.push(
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(`Display at 500*${index} ms: ${letter}`)
          setDialogue(originDialogue => [...originDialogue, letter])
        }, 500*index)
      )
    })

    return () => timers.map((timer) => clearTimeout(timer))  // clean up timers to prevent memory leak
  }, [params]) // params here as dependency of useEffect, see offical document for useEffect for detail

  return (
    <div className="dialogueBox">
      {dialogue.map((letter) => (
        <p>{letter}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Heck yea! That did it. Thank you so much. I knew useEffect was where I needed to go but couldn't get it tow ork in the correct way. Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome~